# Difference between SAS and R results - Nonlinear Regression

Tags: r, sas, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear, nls

Hoping someone can assist with this rather niche question.

I have a routine built in R for analysing depreciation curves, which is fit according to a logistic model with an additional additive intercept term.

```
model = wrapnls(formula = outcome~ 1/(1 + exp(b*age-a))+c,
                data = data,
                start = c(a = 0,b= .01 ,c= 0),
                upper = c(a=100,b=100))
```

I fit this using nlmrt, as the Jacobian is probably poorly conditioned for some of the groups. Using nlmrt I achieve good results which exhibit satisfactory predictive power.

Conversely, when using proc Nlin in SAS, I get a strange effect where the intercept term (c and I for the R and SAS code respectively) effectively tries to dominate, blowing up close to the average of the dataset, while the exponential terms become very small. In reality, the intercept should simply set the lower bound for the terminal value on the asset.

SAS code looks as follows;

```
PROC NLIN DATA = Model_Data METHOD = MARQUARDT;
    PARMS  A = 0, B = 0 I=0;
    BOUNDS  A<5, B<5;
    MODEL outcome= 1/(1+exp(A*age- B))+I;
    ODS OUTPUT ParameterEstimates = Nlmixed_Params;
    RUN;
```

Can anyone help me understand these different behaviours, and maybe give me some advice on how to get SAS to more faithfully reproduce the results from R?

Comment: It's unlikely people can give much help on the basis of the information provided so far, and it also seems the question is asking about differences in implementation of specific functions in particular packages/languages, which is likely to be [off topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I don't think so. I believe the two packages are likely using different optimization routines to arrive at their result. Understanding those differences would require domain expertise in statistics which (if memory serves) makes it on topic according to the guideline that software questions are on topic where they require statistical expertise to solve.

Comment: But please let me know if I can add additional info that might help identify the problem. I'm hoping someone familiar with both packages might be able to give me some advice based on their experience in the area.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the algorithm you chose in SAS that made the difference.

According to [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_nlin_sect024.htm), **METHOD = MARQUARDT** employs the Marquardt algorithm, which is as a Gauss-Newton algorithm with a ridging penalty, as shown in the following update:

$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}^{(u+1)} &= \hat{\boldsymbol \beta}^{(u+1)} + k \Delta \\
\Delta &= (\mathbf{X'X} + \lambda \; \text{diag}(\mathbf{X'X}))^{-} \mathbf{X'r}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\boldsymbol r$ is the residual vector.

> Marquardt’s method is equivalent to performing a series of ridge regressions, and it is useful when the parameter estimates are highly correlated or the objective function is not well approximated by a quadratic.

In your case where there is only one variable, you might not want to do this.

**On the other hand**, what `warpnls` in R does is following, as stated in [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlmrt/nlmrt.pdf).

> wrapnls first attempts to solve the nonlinear sum of squares problem by using nlsmnq, then takes the parameters from that method to call nls.

Checking the source code of `nlsmnq` and the algorithm it calls, `nlxb`, what I understand is `nlxb` is a Gauss-Newton based algorithm since the code computes only the gradient and Jacobian for algorithm update, no second derivatives (in which case is the Newton method). You can see the `nlxb` source code [here](https://github.com/cran/nlmrt/blob/master/R/nlxb.R).

So the best thing you can do is to switch to other options for **METHOD** in SAS to see whether you can get similar results. I'd be curious to see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the reason I chose the Marquardt method was that this link seems to indicate that nlmrt (the R package) actually uses a variant of this method, I might be misunderstanding some key difference here though - do all Marquardt methods use second derivatives? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlmrt/nlmrt.pdf

Comment: I see. You might be right here. They both used Marquardt method, but `nlmrt` in R used a variant of this method. Maybe you want dive into the variant approach to compare. Have you tried other algorithms in SAS? What do the results look like? And again, if you can provide more information about the data set and output from R and SAS, you will be helped better by others.